# Using ReturnsAsync When Automocking in JustMock

Tags: justmock, automocking

JustMock supports `.ReturnsAsync()` when arranging standard mocks, however I am unable to find a way to get this same behavior when Automocking with a `MockingContainer<T>`.

A solution I've found is to wrap the return value in `Task.FromResult<T>()`. This fulfills the expected `Task<T>` return type of the async function, however the syntax is a bit clunky.

```cs
service
    .Arrange<IRepository>(r => r.SomeAsyncMethod("input"))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult<ISomeModel>(resultModel));
```

Ideally, I would like to avoid building the `Task<T>` return values manually and just rely on `.ReturnsAsync()` to handle the conversion.

```cs
service
    .Arrange<IRepository>(r => r.SomeAsyncMethod("input"))
    .ReturnsAsync(resultModel);
```

It's possible the APIs just aren't there, but I want to ensure I'm not just missing some special syntax to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed with Telerik staff that it's not currently possible to use `.ReturnsAsync()` for automocking.

The [feature request](https://feedback.telerik.com/justmock/1635977-using-returnsasync-when-automocking) has been created.